# Eclipse: How can I execute a launch configuration programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have various launch configuration files in my Eclipse project. Is there any way how I can execute an arbitrary launch configuration programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

```
       ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();

       ILaunchConfigurationType type =     manager.getLaunchConfigurationType("org.eclipse.cdt.launch.applicationLaunchType");
       ILaunchConfiguration[] lcs = manager.getLaunchConfigurations(type);

            for (ILaunchConfiguration iLaunchConfiguration : lcs) {
                if (iLaunchConfiguration.getName().equals("Test PThread")) {
                    ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy t = iLaunchConfiguration.getWorkingCopy();
                    ILaunchConfiguration config = t.doSave();
                    if (config != null) {
                        // config.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null);
                        DebugUITools.launch(config, ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE);
                    }
                }
            }
```