# Eclipse plugin to create debug configurations

Tags: eclipse, debugging, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse: How can I execute a launch configuration programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104238/eclipse-how-can-i-execute-a-launch-configuration-programmatically)

I want to write an Eclipse Plugin that can programmatically create Debug Launch configurations for 'Remote Java Application' and also Launch the configuration programmatically.

Is this possible? Can someone give me pointers to get me started?

I don't have a great deal of experience authoring Eclipse plugins but I am quite experienced using it for my daily dev work.

I am keen on writing this plugin to simply my debugging process which currently involves manually launching a debug configuration for every JVM (at least 3) that I want to debug, which slows me down tremendously.

Comment: This duplicate question has an answer which points to a great article on exactly how to do this.  I've book marked that article and have used it successfully several times.

Answer (score 1):

To create the actual plugin, there are several example ones available in Eclipse if you have the Eclipse PDE installation. Look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) for help to get started.

That guide will get you a sample application with a toolbar button and a meny alternative. Alter the code to make it look like you want, then use the help from the other comments to launch the programs.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a good step-by-step approach to take.