# Scriptable Eclipse run/debug configuration

Tags: java, bash, eclipse, automation

Is it possible to script Eclipse IDE (from say BASH, python, Java), to execute a Run or Debug Configuration for a given project in my workspace?

These are saved in .launch files at project root, but how can I execute one such launch configuration automatically?

Given a working project, I'd like to automatically achieve what is done in GUI by Run -> Run Configurations -> (pick a named config) -> Run button.

A named run configuration *could* be "C/C++ Application" or "GDB segger J-link Debugging"->"stm32f4", or **any other** run configuration imaginable.

Specifically I'm using gnuarmeclipse and like to automatically flash and run tests on my embedded target (stm32f4, but my question is generic). It would be great if I didn't have to make two project setups for running the same code on same target -- one for automatic test, and one for Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen done.

Comment: The java tag should probably be replaced with c++ then.

Comment: No simpler way than: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104238/eclipse-how-can-i-execute-a-launch-configuration-programmatically   ?