# How to get the list of external tools in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Eclipse knows external tools (menu run->external tools) and I would like to show the list of external tools on a right click in my view so the user can select a tool which I then execute.

I however simply fail to find the external tools.
The code I have now dumps the commands (and there are plenty) but I do not find the external tools I created.

```
ICommandService commandService=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
Command[] allCommands = commandService.getDefinedCommands();
for(Command curCommand :allCommands) {
    Category cat = curCommand.getCategory();
    System.out.print(cat.getName()+"  ");
    System.out.println(curCommand.getName());
}
```

Where can I find a list of external tools?

Comment: What is an "external command", and are you sure they're this kind of Command?

Comment: In Eclipse `Command` represents an internal command, part of the command/handler system. What do you mean by 'external command'

Comment: It seems to be extranal tools that you can find in the run menu command.

Comment: The external tools dialog is part of the Eclipse Launch system. I can't see a way to easily list everything in that dialog that doesn't involve using internal classes, You can list a single launch configuration type (such as 'Ant Build') using something like the code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330757/2670892)

Comment: I tried the code you linked to but it returned no results. As to the explanation with the code this is for ant "programs" So I created a ant launcher but again no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info of greg I found the following to work in my case.

```
ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
ILaunchConfigurationType type =     manager.getLaunchConfigurationType("org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramLaunchConfigurationType"); //$NON-NLS-1$
ILaunchConfiguration[] lcs = manager.getLaunchConfigurations(type);
```

This works for program launch configurations because I use the key ("org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramLaunchConfigurationType".
If you do not know which type is your command use getLaunchConfigurationTypes() to find all types and list the names to find the Type you need.
There are plenty.